# get google calendar holiday nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

### I want to get google calendar holiday

#### this function is from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

work well with only calendarID of me
...........

```js
 function listEvents(auth) {
       var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
       calendar.events.list({
       auth: auth,
       calendarId: 'en.thai#holiday@group.v3.calendar.google.com',
       timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
       maxResults: 10,
       singleEvents: true,
       orderBy: 'startTime'
       }, function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
             console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
             return;
       }
       var events = response.items;
       if (events.length == 0) {
          console.log('No upcoming events found.');
       } else {
         console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            var event = events[i];
            var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
            console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
          }
        }
      });
     }
```

the problem is when i use calendarID as 'primary' and 'ownuser@gmail.com' work ***but not on***  any calendar url such as

*en.thai#holiday@group.v3.calendar.google.com |*
*en.th#holiday@group.v3.calendar.google.com |*
*`en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com`*  please help thank you

calenderId : 'me' or 'primary...........
output : 'list of all events'

calenderId : en.th#holiday@group.v3.calendar.google.com.......
output : The API returned an error: Error: Not Found

Answer (score 1):

try calendarId: `en.th#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com`

you can test it via: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

if you try this api, you can find a calendarId of your own country

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

Comment: it works with `calendarId: encodeURIComponent('en.th#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com')`